# React Hook Form validation using nested custom checkbox component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I am using React Hook Form. I've made a custom checkbox which looks like this:

```
const Checkbox = ({ text, className, setCheckbox, checkbox }) => {
  const { register } = useFormContext();
  const statute = register("statute");
  return (
    <Wrapper className={className}>
      <StyledLabel>
        <div>{text}</div>
        <StyledInput
          type="checkbox"
          name="statute"
          onChange={(e) => {
            statute.onChange(e);
            setCheckbox && setCheckbox(!checkbox);
          }}
        />
        <Checkmark />
      </StyledLabel>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Checkbox (Checkbox.js) is nested in a parent component (Register.js):

```
const Register = ({ setRegisterView }) => {
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    statute: Yup.bool().oneOf([true], "You need to accept the page statute."),
  });

  const methods = useForm({
    mode: "onSubmit",
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
  });

  const {
    register: validate,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
  } = methods;

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(registerProcess)}>
          <StyledCheckbox
            text="Accept the page statute."
            setCheckbox={null}
            checkbox={null}
          />
          {errors.statute && <Error>{errors.statute.message}</Error>}
          <LoginButton type="submit">SIGN UP</LoginButton>
        </Form>
      </FormProvider>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

The problem is that when I check the checkbox I get an information in errors.statute.message: `` statute must be a `boolean` type, but the final value was: `"on"`. ``.

When I change this:

```
onChange={(e) => {
            statute.onChange(e);
            setCheckbox && setCheckbox(!checkbox);
          }}
```

to this:

```
{...register("statute")}
```

then it works great and errors.statute.message shows correct message just when checked=false in checkbox input. But I need to have the extended version of onChange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you not link the returned `ref` of the `register` call to your `<StyledInput />`. So just spread the return value of `register` - in the code example below i also omitted the `name` prop as it is included in `statute`. [Here](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/3b600f2c6a4860390711855f6ea735f70244b66a/src/types/form.ts#L151) you can find all the props  `register` will return.

```
<StyledInput
  type="checkbox"
  {...statute}
  onChange={e => {
    statute.onChange(e);
    setCheckbox && setCheckbox(!checkbox);
  }}
/>
```

[image: Edit StyledInput (forked)]

Comment: Yes that's it! It works great now! Thank You!